# add year + average rainfall from array

Tags: java, arrays

I am told to **Use nested for loops. The outer loop loops through the years. The inner loop will read and total each year's rainfall amounts and print the average of that year.**

```
public class Rainy {

int years[] = {1, 2, 3};
double rain1[] = {1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 1.5};
double rain2[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.0, 3.5, 1.0};
double rain3[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0};

public void average(int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        sum = sum + data[i];
    }
    average = (double)sum/data.length;
    System.out.println("Average value of array element is " + average);
}}
```

but I am not sure of how to put years in there since the output is gonna be different from what he asks.
this is what the output should look like

> The average for year 1 is 2.54.

> The average for year 2 is 2.46.

> The average for year 3 is 3.50.

So isn't that just in the print??? perhaps I'm just misunderstanding

Comment: Were the arrays given to you in that format or have you created those yourself?

Comment: Hello, they were given to me and I just have to find the average.

Comment: Is it a must that you use nested for loops? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to do so with your years array and rainfall arrays separated

Comment: Yeah, for some reason this is the way my professor has instructed me to do it. I was told it was the most efficient way?

Comment: Was there any mention of using a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: I don't think there was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `average` method needs to print the year number along with the average, it needs to know the year number.  The usual and best way of communicating necessary data to methods is through method arguments.  Pass the year number as an additional `int` argument:

```
public void average(int yearNo, int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        sum = sum + data[i];
    }
    average = (double)sum/data.length;
    System.out.println("Average for year " + yearNo + " is " + average);
}
```